# C# my rich textbox keeps adding all the song names instead of just 1 at the time

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i'm making a little music program for school, and i keep having problems wiht my  richtextbox (rtb), it keeps adding all the songs from before and i don't know how to fix  it without cleaning it over and over again everytime i click the button.

```
private void AddSongKtab()
{
    SongKtab[nr] = new SongInfo();

    string m_SongName;
    string m_SongLocation;

    ofdOpenKtab.ShowDialog();

    m_SongName = ofdOpenKtab.SafeFileName;
    m_SongLocation = ofdOpenKtab.FileName;

    SongKtab[nr].SongName = m_SongName;
    SongKtab[nr].SongLocation = m_SongLocation;

    tbAddKtab.Text = "";

    tbAddKtab.Text = m_SongName;

    rtbExtraKtab.AppendText("added" + m_SongName + "\n");
    rtbExtraKtab.AppendText("Located at " + m_SongLocation + "\n\n");

    rtbSongsKtab.ScrollToCaret();

    nr++;

    showAllKtab();
}

private void showAllKtab()
{
    int m_index;

    rtbExtraKtab.Clear();

    for (m_index = 0; m_index < nr; m_index++)
    {
        rtbSongsKtab.AppendText(SongKtab[m_index].SongName + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: wpf? silverlight? winform? asp.net? ... ??

Comment: could you please give this question a more generic title, like "RichTextBox gets set all items of an array instead of only one item"?

Comment: It seems that you call showAllKtab at the end of the first method. So it is only expected that you show all the songs.

Comment: `nr` is the problem. where it is came from and what is the value of that